# remove array element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an dynamic array of multiple checkboxes. when i checked any checkbox then it get its value and put this in array. i want when i uncheck this then value of this checkbox remove from array. thnku..

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var myCheckboxescolour = new Array();
    var myCheckboxesprice = new Array();
    var mycolour;
    var myprice;
    $(".searchcheck").click(function () {
        mycolour = '';
        myprice = '';
        if ($(this).attr('title') == 'colour') {
            if (this.checked == true) {
                myCheckboxescolour.push($(this).val());
            } else {
                if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), myCheckboxescolour)) {
                    myCheckboxescolour.pop($(this).val());
                }
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: What's with the random "`< br / >`"?

Comment: i think this dosent belong there...

Comment: Why try to maintain the state of this array through the life of the page? Why not just build the array from the values when they are needed (like when the form is submitted, perhaps)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var removeValue = $(this).val();

myCheckboxescolour = jQuery.grep(myCheckboxescolour, function(value) {
     return value != removeValue;
     });
```